# IntelliJ IDEA 13: Formatting Code Style for Java "throw new"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ 13's "Code Style" feature to auto-format our Java code, but I can't figure out how to format `throw new Exception("details")` so that the `"details"` portion is on the same line as the `throw new`.

I want this:

```
if (connection == null) {
        throw new SQLException( "ERROR: Attempted to start a database transaction with a null connection." );
```

But I keep getting this after I type <kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (on Mac) to apply the formatting:

```
if (connection == null) {
        throw new SQLException(
            "ERROR: Attempted to start a database transaction with a null connection." );
```

I've tried almost all the Code Style options under `Project Settings` > `Code Style` > `Java` > `Wrapping and Braces` but I can't seem to find the right setting.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is `Project Settings` > `Code Style` > `General` > `Wrap when typing reaches right margin` ticked? I think the autoformatter follows that for whether it should break to a new line or not if your code extends past the `Right margin` defined just above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, well it seems that IntelliJ is creating those line breaks because the contents of my `"details"` are sufficiently long.  There appears to be a small bug where, after shortening the `"details"` String literal and then reapplying code styles, the line break does not revert.